# select dive text without last space

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I need to select the div content (the TEXT only without last space) on mouse click

```
<div>
                    <div id="block1">
                        Please send the following code
                    </div>
                    <div id="block2" style="font-size:40px; background-color:#fffb95;" onclick="selectText('block2')" >
                        @Html.DisplayFor(c => c.GeneratedCode, new { id = "genCode" })
                    </div>
                    <div id="block3">
                        to your vendor to generate an access code which is required for your authentication.
                    </div>
                </div>
```

the script

```
function selectText(containerid) {
        if (document.selection) { // IE
            var range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
            range.select();
        } else if (window.getSelection) {
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));

            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            window.getSelection().addRange(range );
        }
    }
```

the style

```
#block1, #block2, #block3 {
        display: inline;
    }

    .input-lg {
        height: 43px;
    }
```

this is the output before selection 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RZRr.png)
and when i select 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3brM.png)
i want to remove last space from selection

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this? - I just made the generated code in a span, and then I put on the style attribute on the span.

```js
   function selectText(containerid) {
        if (document.selection) { // IE
            var range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
            range.select();
        } else if (window.getSelection) {
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
           range.cloneRange();
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            window.getSelection().addRange(range );
        }
    }
```

```css
#block1, #block2, #block3 {
    display: inline;
}

.input-lg {
    height: 43px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="block1">
        Please send the following code
    </div>
    <div id="block2"  onclick="selectText('block2')">
        <span style="font-size:40px; background-color:#fffb95;">2256</span>
    </div>
    <div id="block3">
        to your vendor to generate an access code which is required for your authentication.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to get the text from `block2` when you click it and you want to get rid of the white space at the end of it. I see jquery tag for post so you can try this

```
$('#block2').on('click', function() {
    const divText = $(this).text().trim();

    console.log(divText);
    return divText;
})
```

not 100% sure this is what you're looking for and I've never use getSelection() but from reading I would assume that if you're going to use getSelection(), use trim() after you get the selection to remove white space